# Uploading massive files with slow Internet connection

Tags: backup, upload

I am uploading a 550 GB backup of my computer to Amazon Glacier, to save space and to provide an extra backup in case my USB drive fails.

However, my ISP is limiting my upload speed to 5 Mbps, which means I only have a maximum upload speed of about 625 KB/s. It's been 24 hours (cumulative; the upload is halted when my computer is off) and I am only 8% into the upload. Along with the hot summer, I fear the upload is starting to overheat my router (it detects it is at 57 degrees Celsius). Packets are starting to get dropped, and latency is going through the roof.

What are my choices? This is the only USB drive I have with so much capacity. I have an old server that does not have enough capacity and uses USB 1.1 slots, but I can find a way to get it to upload day and night. Upgrading the connection is also not an option.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Buy a second drive and rent a small vault at the bank
- Ask a fried or family member that has a dry cellar and put a small save or lockable box there, maybe bolt it to the wall.
- go to a local library or uni and ubload from there. At our uni we have a pretty beefy upload. Like 25 Mbps at least.
- ask your employer

Comment: I'm just a kid, so I can't rent a small vault, the nearest library is about 5 miles away (no bus), and I have no employer. So it looks yet another item to put on my wishlist.